# putting a canvas and textbox on the same line

Tags: canvas, html

I want to put a 40x40 canvas, a text box, and another 40x160 canvas all on the same line in that order, but it does seem to work, this is what I came up with:

```
<span><canvas id="color" width="40" height="40"></canvas></span>
<span><input type="text" id="rbg_value" /></span>
<span><canvas id="color_picker" width="160" height="40"></canvas></span>
```

But when I do that the first canvas is on its own line, and the text box and the other canvas are on a line together. Any ideas of what it could be?

Comment: Probably because they are "block" elements. Try adding style="display: inline;" to your canvas and input elements.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/riateche/MDCGW/). All three elements are on the same line (if frame width is big enough). Maybe some other CSS on your page causes unwanted behaviour. And "display" of canvases must be inline-block" (it seems that's default).

Comment: I don't know since I've never used it, but according to http://www.coursesweb.net/html/html5-canvas_t canvas is a 'block' element.

Comment: I've tried adding style="display: inline;" to each canvas but it still puts them on different lines... maybe you are right and my frame isn't big enough